# Long install Sharepoint 2013 on VSphere 6 VMs / Query too slow

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, vmware, vsphere

Here a diagram of my problem :

[image: Failed installation]

When i install Sharepoint 2013 Entreprise from SRVWEB VM, the install is really long (3 hours and it's me who cancel). In the install log i can read "query too slow" messages. When i execute a query immediatly in SRVBDD VM the SQL query is executed less than 1 ms.

So, i tried to install all product of each VMs on 1 VM :

[image: Success installation]

The installation proceed succefully in 10 minutes.

There is clearly a problem of communication between VMs on the same virtual host.

Here are the technical configuration:

- VHOST1 : VMWare Vsphere 6.0 Upadate 1a
- SRVBDD : Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bits + SQL Server 2014 SP1
- SRVWEB : Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bits + Sharepoint Server 2013 Entreprise with SP1

The firewall and antivirus are disabled on each VMs.

Have you an idea for my issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.

The SQL server was on a different VLAN the other servers.
I put all the servers in the same VLAN and performance are excellent.

I just do not understand why it hinders knowing that the network is the same in the two cases.